# How can you divide rectangle into four simlar uncongruent triangles with no two triangles overlapping?

Tags: geometry

I have the following question:

How can you divide rectangle into four  similar uncongruent triangles with no two triangles overlapping ?
Really i have no idea . Please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, if the longest side is at least twice the shortest.

[image]

And here's a more general construction:

[image]